# In R, how can I count instances of a dummy variable =1?

Tags: r

In R, using a dataset in which possessing quality X is a dummy variable (1 = yes), how many people in a dataset of 60,000 cases possess quality X?
Help! :)

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: Can you give a little more context?  Homework, self-teaching, business context? (Hint: `sum()`)

Answer (score 1):

If variable X is an integer;

```
mtcars$am
[1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> sum(mtcars$am)
[1] 13
```

If variable X is a factor (or character);

```
> sum(as.factor(mtcars$am) == "1")
[1] 13
```

You can check by using `class()`;

```
> class(mtcars$am)
[1] "numeric"
> class(as.factor(mtcars$am))
[1] "factor"
```

mtcars is a build in dataset for R (you can use `data()`) to see a list of built in datasets.